# AWS ECS Task on private subnet connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-security-group

Is it possible to access a public domain e.g. `foo.bar.com` from an AWS ECS task running on a private subnet? It is convenient for me that the task is running on a private subnet since it can be easily accessible from other ECS tasks running on the same private subnet (same AZ, VPC and region).

I am reading different contradicting opinions:

- Some say that this is not possible and I must configure a NAT Gateway or NAT instance
- Others say that this is possible as long as you specify the right outbound rules for your security groups. But outbound rules can only be configured using IP ranges and not specific domains.

What is actually the case here?

Comment: "Some say that this is not possible and I must configure a NAT Gateway or NAT instance"  is absolutely correct when running ECS task in private subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `NAT Gateway` and add a route in the route table for your subnet. Without a `NAT Gateway` (or NAT instance, but those are considered obsolete), you cannot connect to the public internet from your private subnets.

Answer (score 1):

> - Some say that this is not possible and I must configure a NAT Gateway
>   or NAT instance

That is absoutely correct.

> - Others say that this is possible as long as you specify the right outbound rules for your security groups.

This is entirely incorrect.

---

> It is convenient for me that the task is running on a private subnet since it can be easily accessible from other ECS tasks running on the same private subnet

It would be just as accessible to those services if it was in a public subnet in the same VPC. Resources do not have to be in the same subnet to access each other, they just have to be in the same VPC.

Comment: Also for security purposes, I need them to reside on private subnets.